# Working with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Our team is way too excited with the alpha release of Angular 2 and we're just eagerly waiting for it's stable release and getting started with it.
But during the ng-conf 2015 on Angular 2 by Misko, we came across following things which made me confused

1. TypeScript! Is it really needed to use typescript to gain better performance instead of writing plain simple JS code we've been doing all along. We've came across a few comments that says typescript helps in better performance.
2. ES6 features. Since angular 2 will be using a lot of es6 features, would that mean we'll have to wait for all the browsers support at least those features needed by angular 2 before we can kick start with it on our  production applications.
3. Web components. Since angular 2 provides the facility to create web components and I've came across a few blogs on creating your own (using polymer), how hard is it gonna be for our team to create them? Or is it better if we just stick to old directives creation thing ?
4. Performance. I've seen this video of [Angular + React](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQM0K6YG18s) which provides a good comparison of angular vs angular + react vs angular 2. But I'm not sure if that's the case that angular 2 is really fast all the way or if we can go ahead with building angular + react app to avoid waiting for angular 2 to stabilize or the browsers to have support for es6 features that angular uses.

I'm not sure I've structured my question well, but above are my concerns before I start learning angular 2 because with their demonstration of angular 2 + typescript seemed like it's gonna involve a lot of earning curve for me and my team.

I'll really appreciate if someone can clarify on the above listed concerns I have.

Thanks.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Perhaps you'd better off posting it in somewhere else (even in the official GitHub repo where maybe only bug issues are accepted).

Comment: @DanielA.White my question are my concerns I've listed above.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> TypeScript! Is it really needed to use typescript to gain better performance instead of writing plain simple JS code we've been doing all along. We've came across a few comments that says typescript helps in better performance.

TypeScript is about static analysis for better type-safety. It also has a pretty nice suite of editor tools (e.g. WebStorm). You don't need it for performance. It's more a tool for helping you author. Personally though, I love it.

I've begun migrating some of my existing open-source libraries to TypeScript because it's so much easier to work with. For example, check out Task Runner [before](https://github.com/bvaughn/task-runner/tree/bd7e81477f51fe104bcdad5e3c86528d0b6ab713/source) and [after](https://github.com/bvaughn/task-runner/tree/master/source/tr).

> ES6 features. Since angular 2 will be using a lot of es6 features, would that mean we'll have to wait for all the browsers support at least those features needed by angular 2 before we can kick start with it on our production applications.

A lot of ES6 features can be polyfilled. Check out https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills.

> Web components. Since angular 2 provides the facility to create web components and I've came across a few blogs on creating your own (using polymer), how hard is it gonna be for our team to create them? Or is it better if we just stick to old directives creation thing ?

Web components are also polyfillable (see [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/start/platform.html)). In this case, I'd suggest you follow the Angular team's recommended practices for creating your components. Also perhaps keep an eye on what's coming out of the Polymer team in this regard.

> Performance. I've seen this video of Angular + React which provides a good comparison of angular vs angular + react vs angular 2. But I'm not sure if that's the case that angular 2 is really fast all the way or if we can go ahead with building angular + react app to avoid waiting for angular 2 to stabilize or the browsers to have support for es6 features that angular uses.

This sounds to me like premature optimization. Build for (plain) Angular first and optimize only if you notice performance problems in particular parts of your application.

Comment: so how much effort you think will involve for my team(working on angular 1.x and purely es5) to absorb everything you stated above and how beneficial would be for us to shift entirely to typescript + angular 2 ?

Comment: Both of those are impossible for me to say. I don't know your team or your project. All I can tell you is that I (personally) love working with TypeScript. I've migrated 2 of my existing projects to it (formFor and Task Runner) and I'll be starting my new projects with it. It's that nice. As for Angular 2...whether you should use it or not depends on several factors: how big is your current project? When is the release date? What browsers are you targeting? If your answers include "pretty big", "pretty soon", or "the majority of browsers" then you should probably stick with Angular 1.x for now

Answer (score 20):

> 1. TypeScript! Is it really needed to use typescript to gain better performance instead of writing plain simple JS code we've been doing all along. We've came across a few comments that says typescript helps in better performance.

TypeScript is **not** required to use Angular2.

Most examples you see will use JavaScript:

- `classes` (ES6)
- `decorators` (ES7/Typescript)
- `types` - (Typescript)

Except, browsers don't support those features yet so all Angular2 source will need to be transpiled to ES5.

So in ES5:

- `classes` can be faked by extending prototypes
- `decorators` can be faked using wrapper functions
- `types` aren't really necessary to begin with, they're synctatic sugar added for safety

It would be unrealistic to expect existing users to inherit the risk of using experimental/bleeding-edge standards. As such, the documentation covers writing Angular2 apps in ES5, ES6/7, and Typescript.

*Aside: I personally prefer not to use TypeScript. Traceur can be configured to support with experimental extensions for @decorators, and [system.js](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) provides a polyfill for the proposed [es6-moduler-loader](http://guybedford.com/practical-workflows-for-es6-modules) spec.*

Here's a look at the [Angular2 Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/).

[image: Angular2.io Documentation]

> 2. ES6 features. Since angular 2 will be using a lot of es6 features, would that mean we'll have to wait for all the browsers support at least those features needed by angular 2 before we can kick start with it on our production applications.

As I said already, ES6 isn't officially supported yet in all browsers. Even if it were, most sites will still require a polyfill to provide backwards compatibility to older browsers.

One of the cool features of the [`es6-module-loader`](http://guybedford.com/practical-workflows-for-es6-modules) is the ability to dynamically load dependencies on the fly. By the time Angular2 is out of beta, it should be easy to incorporate this into your app as a feature-detection strategy.

> 3. Web components. Since angular 2 provides the facility to create web components and I've came across a few blogs on creating your own (using polymer), how hard is it gonna be for our team to create them? Or is it better if we just stick to old directives creation thing?

Not hard although you may need to use Angular2-specific web components. The reason being, Angular2 is more than a front-end web framework. It's can also be used for isomorphic (ie prerender on the back-end), native, and mobile apps. That means, touching the DOM directly is highly discouraged.

As for the creation of the components themselves... It's no different than creating any other component in Angular2. Unlike the old MVC model of grouping code by type (ie models, views, controllers), the component model encourages grouping code by context.

When you import a reusable component, it should come with any directives, services, etc required to use it.

For an example, see the  I created. In addition to cloning the repo directly from GH, the code can be installed and imported directly via JSPM.

Simply `import` it, add the component class to your view `directives` and any `<ng2-markdowm>` element in your template will just work. It doesn't get much easier than that.

> 4. Performance. I've seen this video of Angular + React which provides a good comparison of angular vs angular + react vs angular 2. But I'm not sure if that's the case that angular 2 is really fast all the way or if we can go ahead with building angular + react app to avoid waiting for angular 2 to stabilize or the browsers to have support for es6 features that angular uses.

There are 3 major performance improvements introduced in Angular2.

**1. 2-way data binding is no longer the default**

Elements that require data binding need to be explicitly marked in the template (ie don't fret, the new syntax makes this really simple). As a result the overhead required to do dirty checking on the DOM is dramatically reduced.

That means, no more $scope, $scope.apply(), and weird scoping rules in the HTML markup. Instead, the hierarchy of custom `<elements>` is defined in the Angular2 components.

**2. Angular2 leverages the virtual DOM**

jQuery made it extremely simple to directly manipulate the DOM. As a result, it also made it extremely easy for inexperienced developers to thrash the DOM and trigger layout reflows via frequent incremental updates.

The VDOM is basically a simplified in-memory representation of the DOM. Incremental updates get applied directly to the VDOM which later get applied to the actual DOM in batches.

Aside from network requests, DOM manipulation is JavaScript's greatest performance weakness. The VDOM on the other hand is an order of magnitude faster. Instead of expecting devs to follow 'best practices' by manually batching updates to the DOM, Angular handles batching transparently.

Fewer DOM manipulations = less UI rendering/reflows = a much more responsive user experience.

**3. Angular2 runs on a background worker**

This isn't exactly a new concept. Desktop GUIs have worked this way for years, it just wasn't technically possible the introduction of HTML5 background workers.

In most desktop applications, the main context runs synchronously+ and the UI runs asynchronously in it's own separate thread. That makes the user experience responsive regardless of whatever the application is doing in the main context.

*+Note: This isn't necessarily true, but for clarity sake.*

In the browser, all execution happens in the main context+. That means, every time Javascript has to block on a CPU-heavy operation, the user interface becomes unresponsive to the user. This is not ideal and makes for a lousy/inconsistent user experience.

*+Note: In practice browser implementations vary greatly but lets keep things simple.*

With web workers, it's possible to push everything but the DOM+ into a background worker context. Ideally, Javascript's should have little-or-no impact on UI responsiveness.

*+Note: The DOM's state still needs to be accessible to the renderer.*

One side-effect this transition is, the Angular2 architecture is now completely decoupled from the UI/DOM. Meaning, it's now possible to write UI adapters for other platforms (ex for IOS, Android, SmartTVs, etc) that run on the same Angular2 code natively.

**React**

As far as I can tell React is using all of the same performance improvements as Angular. They use the VDOM to batch updates, and mentioned native portability to other platforms so I assume they went through the same architectural change as Angular.

Honestly, using background processing to free up the UI is just another step in the evolution to reach feature parity with desktop applications.

**Angular2 vs React**

I encourage you to [watch the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQM0K6YG18s) again all the way to the end. The presenter screwed up when he wrote the code so the live demo wasn't an honest comparison.

With that said, it doesn't really matter which is faster. Neither will be dramatically faster than the other but they'll both be dramatically more responsive and scalable compared to other UI frameworks.

---

**Update:**

Rewrote the section about web components to better answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Angular 2.0 does promise to work well with Web Components and Polymer, but in the current stage, i.e. Angular 2.0 alpha, it doesn't work ([see this](https://github.com/rkirov/youtube-app/blob/master/readme.mk)). So you'll have to wait for a while I guess.